# Unwrinkle paper

Tags: paper

I was writing on a sheet of paper for something important. I used the eraser and accidentally scrunched up the paper a bit, not ripping it but wrinkling it. Is there a way to fix the paper and make it beautifully flat, not just curved by rubbing it over a table edge?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One thing you might try is to iron it. It works pretty well, but you have to be careful, or you might end up burning it. Generally, you put a piece of fabric over it and iron it gently to avoid tearing it.

Comment: @interwebz no problem

Comment: Also, keep an eye on your steam. The paper lives through an ironing no problem, but the ink can smudge if you aren't careful. It's not like a shirt! If it's a really important paper, try it out on a few test sheets first!

Answer (score 1):

Place the sheet of paper inside a heavy book or between two heavy flat surfaces, leave it for a few hours..viola..this technique is used in flower pressing

Comment: You should increase the humidity a bit for best effect, holding it over a steaming pot should do it and impart a nice curry smell.  Also I would advise placing it between two fresh clean sheets of paper into the book lest the ink transfer onto the damp paper.